# PDF JavaScript deletePages

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I'm working on a stupid hack to make it harder for users in my org to "save" certain pdfs when they're loaded in a browser window.  The best I can think of (other than using certificate encryption, which isn't an option right now) is to create a "Will Save" event and delete all pages in the document before it's saved.

Based on the [PDF Javascript API](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf) this should be pretty easy.

```
//-------------------------------------------------------------
//-----------------Do not edit the XML tags--------------------
//-------------------------------------------------------------

//<Document-Actions>
//<ACRO_source>Document Will Save</ACRO_source>
//<ACRO_script>
/*********** belongs to: Document-Actions:Document Will Save ***********/
this.deletePages(0, this.numPages - 1);
//</ACRO_script>
//</Document-Actions>
```

However, when I hit save, I get the following error.  This happens even if I just do `this.deletePages(0, 0)` or any other combination of numbers.  Does anyone have any idea what stupid error I might be making?

```
TypeError: Invalid argument type.
Doc.deletePages:1:Document-Actions:Document Will Save
 ===> Parameter nEnd.
```

Side note, I found another way of "solving" this, which is to call `this.closeDoc()` in the Will Save event.  This causes the browser and adobe to crash (it works!  but at what cost?).

Comment: Could you instead render your PDFs to PNG? You could then watermark them effectively, and document magpies only get a fixed-resolution copy.

Comment: This is an option I've considered.  I'd prefer to avoid this, since it's a hassle and doesn't really offer much more security.  Combined with the 'technique' of preventing users from right-clicking on a page that BryanH mentions below, it would probably be acceptable.

Comment: True, although at least it is watermarkable. Another idea, which admittedly doesn't tackle the issue of users nicking your PDF: I'd suggest you consider encrypting and locking the PDF against clipboard copying, so that users at least cannot (easily) copy the content out of the document.

Comment: When a PDF is uploaded into the system, iTextSharp applies all of the security restrictions you've mentioned.  The main problem is that the user will act the fool and save the PDF and e-mail it to someone.  Obviously, we should have an internal certificate that is used to encrypt the document.  Failing that, I'd say we should password protect the document.  The problem is typing in a password is too much work for the end users, and setting up the certificate scheme will take time and money.  Something stupid and hacky needs to be put into place now that at least discourages the stupidest.

Comment: Righty-ho. I did wonder whether the object tag in a web page could be used to specify a read password, but I don't think this is supported by Acrobat Reader ([see here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf)). Equally it would need widespread support across several reader softwares to be of any use, in any case `:(`.

Comment: Last suggestion (don't know if your point about Acrobat X makes this redundant) - embed it using an object tag from [this tool](http://www.pdfobject.com/generator.php). Quite a few menus/toolbars can be turned off.

Comment: That's the exact tool I'm using at the moment.  The plugin for Acrobat X doesn't seem to respect any of the settings.

Answer (score 1):

This is akin to the "technique" to "prevent" users from right-clicking on images and saving them.

Maybe you want to step back a bit and examine *why* you don't want the users to do stuff with the PDFs. Are you trying to apply a technical answer to a non-technical problem?

You are trying to prevent the normal behavior of a web browser, so you will spend a lot of time trying to get this right, and you have no guarantee your methods will not break with the next browser version. Tech-savvy users will bypass whatever technique you come up with in short order.

Basically, you are saying, "I want to prevent a user from doing something (opening/viewing/printing) with a file they've already downloaded to their computer."

Comment: Yes, as I said I'm fully aware of how stupid this is.  However, the old "solution" from before my time was to hide the toolbar in the Acrobat Plugin, which no longer works in Acrobat X because of the HUD.

I have already informed my client of the million ways that any of these systems can be bypassed, but this is an internal application targeted at non-tech savvy users.  It's mostly a deterrent.

Comment: Whoever left the -1, please tell me why so I can learn. Thank you.